# I want this condition work to fill validation form for inputs

Tags: javascript, html

```
const userinfo = () => {
  // Trim -- remove spaces
  username = document.getElementById("username").value.trim();
  email = document.getElementById("email").value.trim();
  password = document.getElementById("password").value.trim();
  confirmpassword = document.getElementById("confirmpassword").value.trim();
  console.log(username, email, password, confirmpassword);
};
```

```
const checkinput = () => {
  // Not Null
  if (
    username.trim().length !== 0 &&
    email.trim().length !== 0 &&
    password.trim().length !== 0 &&
    confirmpassword.trim().length !== 0
  ) {
    return true;
  } else {
    // Style Java
    // Element.style.typeof style(Border, Size, Font, Color)
    msgPassword.style.border = "2px solid red";
    msgConfirm.style.border = "2px solid red";
    document.getElementById("error-allength").innerHTML =
      "place fill all filed ";
    return false;
  }
};
```

I want this condition  work to fill validation form for inputs, I think it's impoosible to solve it, please help me !!

Comment: please share your HTML code to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const checkinput = () => {
  if (
    username.trim().length !== 0 ||
    email.trim().length !== 0 ||
    password.trim().length !== 0 ||
    confirmpassword.trim().length !== 0
  ) {
    return true;
  } else {
    
    msgPassword.style.border = "2px solid red";
    msgConfirm.style.border = "2px solid red";
    document.getElementById("error-allength").innerHTML =
      "place fill all filed ";
    return false;
  }
};
```

Comment: Also there's no need to trim() again since all strings are already trimmed